# How to read contact name and number from contact list

Tags: android

I'm trying to read contact numbers from users contact list. Here is my code

```
Cursor cursor = getContacts();
if(cursor.getCount()>0){
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        int numberField = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        textViewDisplay.append("Name: ");
        textViewDisplay.append(displayName+"Number :"+numberField);
        textViewDisplay.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any problem?

Comment: yea i am getting contact name but not getting contact number it returns -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking `cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN)` into `int`. So the method as it says returns the index of `COLUMN` sent to it as parameter. You need Phone Number which will never be contained by an `int` as its size is always be greater than 4 bytes, and also it contains some special characters like `+`

So you need to take your `Number` to some `String` variable

Use `String numberField = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));`

as suggested by Anuj.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
String numberField = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

instead of

```
int numberField = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
```

Comment: Illegal state exception occurred while fetching contacts.

Comment: use this URI `Uri phoneUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;`

Comment: and for name use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));`

Answer (score 1):

It returns "1" means that contact has phone number. try this,

```
 String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                      String cNumber="";
                      if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
                      {
                          Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                          phones.moveToFirst();
                          cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                          phones.close();

                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
public void readContacts() {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                        // Get contact id (id)
                        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 

                        // Get contact name (displayName)
                        String displayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                        // Get Phone Number.... 

                        Uri URI_PHONE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                        String SELECTION_PHONE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?";
                        String[] SELECTION_ARRAY_PHONE = new String[] { id };

                        Cursor currPhone = cr.query(URI_PHONE, null,SELECTION_PHONE, SELECTION_ARRAY_PHONE, null);
                        int indexPhoneNo = currPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                        int indexPhoneType = currPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);

                        if (currPhone.getCount() > 0) {

                            while (currPhone.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNoStr = currPhone.getString(indexPhoneNo);
                                String phoneTypeStr = currPhone.getString(indexPhoneType);
                            }
                        }
                        currPhone.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            cur.close();
        }
```

Comment: It throws CursorIndexOutofBoundException

Comment: ok, follow this http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html , here is the good example for you